# Separability of the Space of all Real-Valued functions over $[a,b]$ with a Continuous First Derivative

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm reading Neal Carothers' *Real Analysis* and I'm stuck on the following question: Let $f$ be real-valued, continuously differentiable function over $[a,b]$ and let $\epsilon>0$. Show that there is a polynomial $p$ such that $||f-p||<\epsilon$ and $||f'-p'||<\epsilon$ (here, $||g||$ is the sup norm metric). From this, show that space of all real-valued functions over $[a,b]$ with a continuous first derivative is separable.

I'm also given that the metric of this space is $d(f,g)=||f-g||+||f'-g'||$.

Here's what I've done so far: I've taken $f'$, and by Weierstrass's approximation theorem, concluded that there is a sequence of polynomials $(q_n)$ that converges uniformly to $f'$ over $[a,b]$. Since $f'$ is continuous, it is integrable, so, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, I have: $$\int_a^x f' \left({t}\right) \ \mathrm d t=f(x)-f(a)$$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$. I also have, by uniform convergence and integrability of polynomials: $$\int_a^x f' \left({t}\right) \ \mathrm d t=\lim_{n \mathop \to \infty} \int_a^x q_n \left({t}\right) \ \mathrm d t$$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$. Also, by letting $p_n(x)$ be the antiderivative of $q_n(x)$, I have, by the fundamental theorem of calculus: $$\lim_{n \mathop \to \infty} \int_a^x q_n \left({t}\right) \ \mathrm d t=\lim_{n \mathop \to \infty} (p_n(x)-p_n(a))$$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$. Putting everything together, we see that: $$f(x)=lim_{n \mathop \to \infty} (p_n(x)-p_n(a)-f(a))$$ That is, we have a sequence of polynomials that converges uniformly to $f$ and whose derivatives converges uniformly to $f'$. So there is a polynomial $p$ such that$||f-p||<\epsilon$ and $||f'-p'||<\epsilon$.

The problem I'm having is showing the separability of the space using this information. Clearly, from what we've just shown, the set of all polynomials over $[a,b]$ is a subset of this space and is dense in this space (under the specified metric), but it is not countable. Does anybody have any ideas on how to solve the countability issue? Any help at all would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of all polynomials with rational coefficients is a countable dense subset of the set of all polynomials with real coefficients. Hence it is also a dense subset of $C^1$ by your argument.

To see that it is countable, you can check that there is a bijection with $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty Q^n $ which is a countable union of countable sets.